# PHP Remove specific line return

Tags: tags, preg-replace

After i've done a preg_replace to remove the  TAG 'TagToremove', i still have a line return, would you know if either i could remove it during the preg_replace 
Or After and how ?
Thanks

```
<?php

$strip_list = array('TagToremove');
foreach ($strip_list as $tag)
{
    $temp = preg_replace('/<\/?' . $tag . '(.|\s)*?>/', '', $temp);
}


?>
```

String before Preg_replace:

```
<CodeServiceTransport></CodeServiceTransport>
<PrixTotalCommande>100</PrixTotalCommande>
<TagToremove>
<Ligne>
<ll>hh</ll>
<Id>48</Id>
<SKU>autreID</SKU>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Ligne>
</TagToremove>
<Meta-CodeActivite></Meta-CodeActivite>
<Meta-CodeEnseigne></Meta-CodeEnseigne>
```

String after Preg_replace:

```
<CodeServiceTransport></CodeServiceTransport>
<PrixTotalCommande>100</PrixTotalCommande>

<Ligne>
<ll>hh</ll>
<Id>48</Id>
<SKU>autreID</SKU>
<Quantity>1</Quantity>
</Ligne>

<Meta-CodeActivite></Meta-CodeActivite>
<Meta-CodeEnseigne></Meta-CodeEnseigne>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't parse HTML with regex, use a DOM parser instead.**

Nevertheless, for your specific problem, you have to add an optional linebreak in your regex like that:

```
$temp = preg_replace('~</?' . $tag . '[^>]*>\R?~i', '', $temp);
```

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak (ie. `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n`)

Comment: oops sorry it works ! it just change my indentation adding space on the left.

Comment: @Pipoo:No problem, but for me there're no spaces in front.

Comment: in case would you know how to remove some "spaces" b before tags (indentation) ?

Comment: @Pipoo: Add `\h*` after `\R?` (`[^>]*>\R?\h*`) or change to `[^>]*>\s*`

Comment: do you mean  like this ?    $temp = preg_replace('~</?' . $tag . '[^>]*>\R?\h*', '', $temp);

Comment: @Pipoo: yes, I do. But the second option is better.

Comment: $temp = preg_replace('~</?' . $tag . '[^>]*>\s*', '', $temp); removes all my tags except roots

Comment: @Pipoo: There is probably another error somewhere. I just tried `$temp = preg_replace('~</?' . $tag . '[^>]*>\s*~i', '', $temp);` and it works pretty fine.